# Unity: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\path\gradle.bat'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, sdk

I got this error, when I was adding AdMob and tried to resolve packages.

[image]

While I'm building my project it stucks on the first scene.

**EDIT:**
When I build the project without resolving dependencies I always get this error anyway. I think It stucks for this reason.

Do you guys have any predictions how can I resolve this error and build project.

I'm using Unity 2022.2.11f1

**I tried**

- Use other external tools(JDK, SDK, NDK and Gradle)
- ReInstall the Unity
- ReInstall Ads Mediation (I also tried without Ads Mediation package)
- Build Project on other API versiond
- Force Resolve
- Change `gradlew` file name to `gradlew.bat` (Because it doesn't have any extention)

**NOTE:** This problem appeared before adding AdMob. I resolved it reinstalling Unity. But After adding AdMob I can't resolve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

- **Open** the project
- **Download** [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/gradlew.bat) **gradlew.bat** file
- **Copy** to this path: **\ProjectFolder\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle**
  (This path only avaible if project open)
- Click **Assets** right click and **Reimport**  [(IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZsLJ.png)
  (Save your project if you did any changes)
- **Assets > Mobile Dependency Resolver > Android Resolver > Force
  Resolve** [(IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebo2u.png)
- **AND DONE!**

*Unity Editor: 2022.3.7f1*

*IronSource version: 7.3.0*